# Installation of turtlebot_simulator fails with apt-get

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all, I am facing issues to install the **turtlebot_simulator stack** with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-turtlebot-simulator
```

I get the following error:

```
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] Err http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-amcl amd64 1.12.7-0trusty-20160420-064058-0700
      404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Err http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-voxel-grid amd64 1.12.7-0trusty-20160419-215226-0700
      404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Err http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-turtlebot-stdr amd64 2.2.2-0trusty-20160420-100701-0700
... 
      404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Err http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-turtlebot-simulator amd64 2.2.2-0trusty-20160420-101710-0700
```

First question: How can I solve this problem?

Second question: How can I install the **turtlebot_simulator stack** from source? I read tthe related documentation but I was not able to do it from source. Is it possible to someone give a step by step instructions for this?
Suppose I got the source codes with:

```
git clone https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_simulator.git
```

and now?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235371/installation-of-turtlebot_simulator-fails-with-apt-get/) by [Randerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/25441/randerson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2016-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's recommended to always do an `apt-get update` before trying to install anything. I suspect that new packages have been uploaded since you updated your index. The timestamp on the files it's failing to get are close to a month old suggesting an out of date repo and we just synced new packages yesterday for indigo.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Randerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/25441/randerson/) on 2016-05-27**:
My mistake... Could you help me with the question 2?